# Under the Uniform Hashing Assumption, how close to constant (N/#) must I be to achieve uniform operations in a hash table in java?

Tags: java, hash, linked-list

My task is to code a resize() method for a hash table, in order to achieve constant operations while minimizing memory usage and search or delete times in Java.  Given a hash table utilizing separate chaining, where the table is an array of linked lists, M is the total array length and N is the number of nodes across all of the linked lists.

My professor has said that to achieve constant time operations between 3 and 5 (like search and delete), I must try to have N/M ~ 4 at all times.  Therefore, whenever I add a Node to my hash table, I must check to see if the table must be resized.  My question is: because N/M must approximately be 4, where do I draw the line that the array length (M) should be resized?

Comment: Why not at four??

Comment: Because for a number of nodes that is not divisible by 4, it will be impossible to sort all of the nodes to make the average load N/M 4.  If I have 18 nodes, I can use 4 or 5 linked lists - the average with 4 will be 4.5 and the average with 5 will be 3.6 - so which do I choose?

Comment: It doesn't matter much if it's 4.5 or 3.6. The point is, N/M should go to infinity.